# Object Required Error When Declaring String Variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am fetching a set of names from a database query and then reformatting it to a comma separated list. As I am using this functionallity a few Places in my app, I try to write it as a function getting the sql-query and returning the string.

```
Public Function String_from_query(StrSQL As String) As String

 Dim dbs As Database
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Set dbs = CurrentDb
 Dim results As String
 results = ""
 Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(StrSQL)
 If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If results > "" Then
            results = results & ", "
        End If
        results = results & rs("Navn")
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
 End If
 Set String_from_query = results
End Function
```

This is then called from an event handler:

```
Private Sub Detalj_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
 Dim StrSQL As String
 StrSQL = "SELECT Personer.Navn FROM Personer INNER JOIN Personoppgaver ON Personer.Initialer = Personoppgaver.Initialer WHERE Personoppgaver.Oppgaveid =" & Me.Oppgaveid.Value
 Me.Tekst52.Value = String_from_query(StrSQL)
End Sub
```

If I have the code from the String_from_query function within the event handler and then directly assigns Me.Tekst52 to results, everything works fine. When I refactor the code as shown, I get a "Compile Error, Object required" when I try to run it and a marker on the last line in the sub. (Set String_from_query = results). I am not able to see what is wrong. Any help?

Comment: remove the `Set`. Only required for objects. Not Strings

Comment: Bah, too stupid... After reading around a bit, I got the impression that it was too few set that got you into problems... Worked fine, if you rewrite it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Answered. If you edit your title to something like "Object Required Error When Declaring String Variable", it may be more easily searchable. Just a thought ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyword `Set` is only required when assigning variables to an `Object`. For Access, this would be `Forms`, `Reports`, `Recordsets`, etc. Or other Objects outside of Access (`FileSystemObject`, for example).

When setting strings, dates, numbers, etc, you do not need `Set`.

You can surmise this from the error message as well, `Object required`.